# Загрузка html в div

Tags: jquery

Стоит задача - необходимо реализовать загрузку html страницы в отдельный div на странице. Вроде как для этого можно использовать .load().. Много написано в инете по этому поводу. Например, код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
     <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
             $('#but_load').click(function(){
                 $('#for_load').load('example.html');
             });
         });
     </script>
     <style type='text/css'>
        #for_load{
            width:500px;
            height:300px;
            border:2px solid black;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        #but_load{
            width:500px;
            height:100px;
            border:2px solid black;
        }
     </style>
<head>
<body>
     <div id='for_load'></div>
     <div id='but_load'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

То есть рисуются 2 div'a, первый - блок для загрузки html файла, второй - кнопка. При нажатии на первый запускается функция $('#for_load').load('example.html'); Судя по написанному в инете, именно в данный момент должна загружаться страница в div#for_load. Но ничего не происходит.

Подскажите, в чем может быть ошибка, или что я не правильно делаю.

Comment: Код абослютно рабочий. Проверьте что в консоли при клике на блок

Comment: Запустил в мозилле, все работает..

Надо было сразу консоль посмотреть, протупил. В хроме ругается на путь, говорит, что такого файла нет.

Проблема решена, в принципе. Спасибо. В след раз буду внимательнее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо начинать разхлёбывать кашу с того, что для начала надо понять, обрабатывается ли назначаемый "диву" клик мышью. Для этого просто замените содержимое функции на `alert()`, например. Проверьте. Мне почему-то кажется, что этот див:

```
 <div id='for_load'></div>
```

Не имеет адекватной высоты, и, поэтому клик не обрабатывается. Далее, конечно же, проверить `наличие файла example.html` на существование. Если файл лежит в корне сайта, то лучше бы поставить перед ним слеш: `/example.html.`

Comment: Тупо скопировал его код, создал файл example.html и все работает. Пробовал в FF на Ubuntu

Comment: Вам кажется. С алертами проверял, само собой, всё работает.

Answer (score 0):

Само собой - в ff будет отрабатывать, так как там не реализован механизм безопасности, когда идет обращение к параметрам не находящихся в доме html, в других браузерах данная конструкция не будет работать основанных на chromium, а это наверное все остальные)))...

Если запускать другие браузеры с параметром отключающим безопасность, то можно добиться отображение элементов не входящих в дом html.